# Will frequent insert make select queries slower with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that's frequently written to. There is a crawler that keeps inserting new records.

How will this affect the read performance of the same table in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it will slow it down in two ways. All other things being equal, a larger table will take longer to traverse than a smaller one. Furthermore, if by "frequently" you mean "it's likely to be written to while I'm querying it", then it will increase the load on the server (somewhat), which will also slow it down.

There are all sorts of ways to mitigate both issues (indexing, etc. for the table size, or dirty reads, etc. for the contention problem), but (again, all other things being equal) a table that has less stuff inserted into it less often is going to be faster.

Comment: The effect will also depend on the type of table engine used.

Comment: Sure, but on a given engine the argument still stands. Obviously a memory engine table will be faster than innodb (in most cases), but a memory engine table that's had stuff added to it will still take longer to traverse than a smaller one...

Comment: Table / row locking has a major effect that shows up between MyISAM and InnoDB.